# "react-native-modal-datetime-picker" years list is not scrolling

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-datetimepicker

I tried to find a solution on my own, or at least similar problems with other people, but I failed.

This problem appeared after updating the ***react-native-reanimated*** to version **2.x**. I need it to work with other components, so the option to roll back is not suitable.

[image: how does it look]

The problem occurs only on android. Does anyone know why this might be?

My component code is presented below:

```jsx
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React, { useCallback, useMemo, useState } from 'react';
import TextInput from './TextInput';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { FAB, TouchableRipple } from 'react-native-paper';
import DateTimePickerModal from 'react-native-modal-datetime-picker';
import moment from 'moment';
import { colors } from '../../../styles/colors';
import { CalendarLinear } from '../../../config/images';
import { formatDate } from '../../../helpers';
import { typographySizes } from '../../../styles/typography.style';
import { em } from '../../../styles/sizes';

const minDate = new Date('1900-01-01');
const maxDate = new Date('2038-01-01');

const iconSize = typographySizes.small.fontSize;

const CalendarLinearIcon = () => (
  <CalendarLinear width={iconSize} height={iconSize} fill={colors.muted_dark} />
);

const TextInputDate = (props) => {
  let { value } = props;

  const {
    onChangeText,
    mode = 'date',
    min = minDate,
    max = maxDate,
    locale = 'ru-RU',
    icon = true,
    ...rest
  } = props;

  value = formatDate(value);
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

  const showPicker = useCallback(() => {
    setVisible(true);
  }, []);

  const hidePicker = useCallback(() => {
    setVisible(false);
  }, []);

  const confirmPicker = useCallback(
    (date) => {
      const value = new moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
      setVisible(false);
      onChangeText(value);
    },
    [onChangeText]
  );

  const trailingIcon = useMemo(
    () =>
      (icon && (
        <FAB small style={styles.calendarButton} icon={CalendarLinearIcon} />
      )) ||
      undefined,
    [icon]
  );

  return (
    <>
      <DateTimePickerModal
        isVisible={visible}
        value={new Date(value)}
        mode={mode}
        minimumDate={min}
        maximumDate={max}
        locale={locale}
        onConfirm={confirmPicker}
        onCancel={hidePicker}
      />
      <TouchableRipple
        onPress={showPicker}
        style={{ borderTopLeftRadius: em / 2, borderTopRightRadius: em / 2 }}
        borderless>
        <View>
          <TextInput
            {...rest}
            keyboardType={'numeric'}
            // onChangeText={onChange}
            type={'date'}
            editable={false}
            value={value}
            onFocus={showPicker}
            trailingIcon={trailingIcon}
          />
          <View style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill} />
        </View>
      </TouchableRipple>
    </>
  );
};

TextInputDate.propTypes = {
  value: PropTypes.any.isRequired,
  onChangeText: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  mode: PropTypes.oneOf(['date', 'time', 'datetime', 'countdown']),
  min: PropTypes.instanceOf(Date),
  max: PropTypes.instanceOf(Date),
  locale: PropTypes.string,
};

const styles = {
  calendarButton: {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    shadowOpacity: 0,
    shadowRadius: 0,
    elevation: 0,
    height: iconSize * 2,
    width: iconSize * 2,
  },
};

export default TextInputDate;
```

**UPD1:**

I found this only occurs on small screens. Apparently, a nested scrollable view is formed or something like that.

**UPD2:**

I tried to create a reproducible example in codesandbox but I get an error. I think this is a flaw in the platform. But [this code](https://codesandbox.io/s/red-snowflake-kh066?file=/src/App.js) can help reproduce this problem on your PC.

**UPD3:**

The problem cannot be the minimum or maximum date. Moreover, I do not use the `time` mode.
[image: Everything works fine on a large screen device]

**UPD4:**

Apparently **the issue has nothing to do with *react-native-reanimated***, it just coincided. I have reproduced the issue separately, without this library.

I also [reported](https://github.com/mmazzarolo/react-native-modal-datetime-picker/issues/597) about the issue to the developers.

**UPD5:**

Thanks to the developer's answer, I ran additional tests and it turned out that the real reason for this behavior is in `@react-native-community/datetimepicker`.

The [standard example from the documentation](https://github.com/react-native-datetimepicker/datetimepicker#basic-usage-with-state) reproduces this behavior.

I have also [reported](https://github.com/react-native-datetimepicker/datetimepicker/issues/512) the issue to other developers.

Comment: Looking at the documentation, it says "Min Date. Does not work with 'time' picker on Android". Same for "Max Date."
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-modal-datetime-picker/v/7.6.1#available-props

Comment: @Vega initially there was no answer in the question

Comment: @Vega I can close the question, but it doesn't make sense, since it is not resolved. I can also delete my answer, but now there is no better answer than the answer from the developers.

It was assumed that if someone found a solution, then I would accept it as an answer.

I would not want to delete the question because I am more comfortable using a small screen emulator for a variety of reasons.

What is the best way to proceed?

Comment: @Vega the community does not accept the question where there is a link to the answer from the developers and the answer where there is the answer from the developers. How to be?

Comment: @Vega at the same time, the purpose of the community is completely incomprehensible to me if it does ignore off-topic answers, but at the same time finds fault with the format of the question. At the same time, everything was fine for three months. Is the community trying to help clarify the issue or close the issue for a contrived reason?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The developer [said](https://github.com/react-native-datetimepicker/datetimepicker/issues/512#issuecomment-967463674) there was no point in solving the problem... I agree with him, because this does not occur on real devices.

Answer (score -1):

Looking at the props in the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-modal-datetime-picker/v/7.6.1#available-props), it says "Min Date. Does not work with 'time' picker on Android". Same for "Max Date."

Comment: I added an update to the question